# Haskell: Parsing and processing stream of json requests

Tags: json, haskell, code-duplication, typing

Following code tries to execute a stream of Request objects.

```
{-# LANGUAGE  DeriveGeneric, DeriveDataTypeable #-}
--OverloadedStrings,

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Data
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Request a = Request {
  name         :: String,
  payload      :: a
} deriving (Show, Generic)
instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Request a)
instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (Request a)

class Exe a where
  exe :: (Request a) -> String

data Createuser = Createuser {
  userName       :: String
} deriving (Show, Generic)
instance FromJSON Createuser
instance ToJSON Createuser
instance Exe Createuser where
  exe r = "creating user"

parseCreateUser json = parse json :: Request Createuser

data Deleteuser = Deleteuser {
  userName2       :: String
} deriving (Show, Generic)
instance FromJSON Deleteuser
instance ToJSON Deleteuser
instance Exe Deleteuser where
  exe r = "deleting user"

parseDeleteUser json = parse json :: Request Deleteuser

tojson name payload = encode (Request name payload)
parse bs = let Just p = decode bs in p


sampleDeleteUser = tojson "deleteUser" (Deleteuser "Jigar Gosar")
sampleCreateUser = tojson "createUser" (Createuser "Jigar Gosar")

exeTuple tuple = case tuple of
              ("createUser", a) -> exe $ parseCreateUser $ a
              ("deleteUser", a) -> exe $ parseDeleteUser $ a

main = do
-- This list would be read from socket.
  let tuples = [("createUser", sampleCreateUser), ("deleteUser", sampleDeleteUser)]

  putStr $ unlines [exeTuple tup | tup <- tuples]

  print "end"
```

Is there any way to remove the following duplication?

```
parseCreateUser json = parse json :: Request Createuser
parseDeleteUser json = parse json :: Request Deleteuser
```

I will have to write this for every (Request p) I create.

Also I will have to keep modifying following function every time I create new (Request p)

```
exeTuple tuple = case tuple of
              ("createUser", a) -> exe $ parseCreateUser $ a
              ("deleteUser", a) -> exe $ parseDeleteUser $ a
```

Is this idiomatic haskell code?

Comment: Can you explain what duplication in particular you wish to remove?

Comment: @dfeuer clarified the question in the post itself. thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `parse` directly?  For the input language, I don't know of a better way. You have to know what your commands are.

Comment: @dfeuer yes I can inline parse method in exeTuple.
But I will have to keep modifying the exeTuple method. Is there an alternative to not modifying exeTuple every time a new (Request p) is added?

Comment: If you need to add more requests in another module, say, then that module can define its own `exeTuple2` that calls yours as a fall-back. But in any case, you need some way to dispatch based on those strings; I think your current approach is likely as good as any.

Comment: You might consider combining `exe` and the `parse...` functions because then the compositions will all have the same type: `ByteString -> String` and that will allow you to write `exeTuple` as a lookup into a Map.